# MATLAB - Interpolation in matrix of data

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I currently have a 252x11 double matrix of data where each column is an individual time series. However, some of the data is missing and I would like to interpolate in order to fill in that data since I later need to use an algorithm that requires no blanks or NaNs. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You can use the `interp1` command. The `1` in the name stands for `1D`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider using [inpaint_nans](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4551) which is designed to interpolate NaN elements in a 1-d or 2-d array using non-NaN elements. It can also extrapolate, as it does not use a triangulation of the data.  It also allows different approaches to the interpolation.